# MySQL index on VARCHAR(1000)

Tags: mysql

A `VARCHAR(1000)` column will be included in a `WHERE` clause e.g.

```
WHERE propertyValue IN ('sample, ...')
```

The values will mostly be unique but are not guaranteed/constrained to be.

I want to index this and I am wondering what the best approach is. I realise indexing a column like this will make inserts slower.

Would storing a hash of the value  as a `CHAR(64)` and indexing and searching on that be faster? My thinking is a fixed size value like that would be more suitable for indexing.

I am using 5.1 and INNODB

Comment: When using INDEX all INSERT statements will need to update the INDEX, which might slow down INSERT statements, so - tread carefully when creating INDEX on columns with VARCHAR(1000). Depending on what exactly do you store in this column, you might need to use full INDEX, not partial INDEX when using WHERE x IN (a,b,c)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach will be to use a partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON [...] propertyValue(100) [...]
```

So long as the first 100 characters (in this example) of the columns are reasonably distinctive, this will be more than sufficient to make the index work.